# Adding a new category in column in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, categories, addition, edit, blazor-editform

I cannot add/edit the category column on my sharepoint and I need to make the changes.
I used to go to Library setting and then under column list find category and then add/edit however, now when I do the same. no changes are happening. can someone help in what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.After you changing the vlaue of [Category]  (Choice-type column)

[image]

[image]

2.Upload file to Document library (Or modify the value of the original document) and define the [Category] value for the file (choose [Category] newly added value).

[image]

[image]

3.If you not define the [Category] value for the file. It will display Unassigned(1).

[image]